# ILMerge Error Windows Phone 8 Unresolved assembly reference

Tags: windows-phone-8, ilmerge

I am trying to merge some .net assemblies for Windows Phone 8 using ILMerge.exe (2.12.0803). On their own all assemblies work fine. I can successfully merge assembles which do not contain references to the [Windows.Networking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.networking.aspx) namespace as follows:

> .\ILMerge.exe /lib:"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0"
>   /out:.\WP8\%1\MathToolbox.dll .\%1\MathBase.dll .\%1\PolyFunctions.dll

As soon as I try to include a DLL which uses the Windows.Networking namspace as follows:

> .\ILMerge.exe /lib:"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0"
>   /out:.\WP8\%1\MathToolbox.dll .\%1\MathBase.dll .\%1\PolyFunctions.dll
>   .\%1\RemoteTools.dll

I am recieving the following exception:

> An exception occurred during merging: Unresolved assembly reference
>   not allowed: Windows.    at
>   System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetAssemblyRefIndex(AssemblyNode assembly)    at
>   System.Compiler.Ir2md.GetTypeRefIndex(TypeNode type)    at
>   System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitReferencedType(TypeNode type)    at
>   System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitClass(Class Class)    at
>   System.Compiler.Ir2md.VisitModule(Module module)    at
>   System.Compiler.Ir2md.SetupMetadataWriter(String debugSymbolsLocation)
>   at System.Compiler.Ir2md.WritePE(Module module, String
>   debugSymbolsLocation, BinaryWriter writer)    at
>   System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(String location, Boolean
>   writeDebugSymbols, Module module, Boolean delayS ign, String
>   keyFileName, String keyName)    at
>   System.Compiler.Writer.WritePE(CompilerParameters compilerParameters,
>   Module module)    at ILMerging.ILMerge.Merge()    at
>   ILMerging.ILMerge.Main(String[] args)

Having done some reading this exception suggets ILMerge is unable to locate the Windows.Networking assemblies. I have attempted adding various different flags to ILMERGE including:

> .\ILMerge.exe /lib:"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.0" /targetplatform:v4,"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71"
>   /out:.\WP8\%1\MathToolbox.dll .\%1\MathBase.dll .\%1\PolyFunctions.dll
>   .\%1\RemoteTools.dll

But still get the same exception. If anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think ILMerge actually works with other than pure .NET assemblies, especially when Windows Phone 8 and WinRT projects uses referenced native libraries - that might be that not found "Windows" unresolved assembly.

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines as well but I am using other namespaces within the Windows Phone SDK in the assemblies that work, e.g. MathBase.dll, albeit not part of the Windows.xxx namespaces. I am assuming all WP8 namespaces are drawn from the same cloth, perhaps not.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as no-one else seems to have any additional feedback. I'm going to assume I get this error because I am referencing native libraries for WP8 and ILMerge has not yet caught up as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that ILMerge cannot find the platform's Windows.winmd. When compiling a Windows Phone or Windows Store project, you compile against two main things; The Platform SDK (WinRT) and a .NET SDK. Any tools that run over these assemblies will need both.

In addition to passing the .NET assembly folder, try passing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.0\Windows Metadata directory" as a lib argument.

Make note, ILMerge is based on an older version of CCI (http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) so even after doing above, may still have trouble consuming the WinRT metadata format which is slightly different to .NET's.