# Merging .NET assemblies on Windows Store / Phone 8 / Portable Class Library

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library, ilmerge

Is there a way to embed multiple dependent assemblies into a single one for projects written on the following platform types: Windows Store Apps, Windows Phone 8, Portable Class Library?

I know that for regular .Net projects there is ILMerge, but on the aforementioned project types [it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15455812/475673). Embedding assemblies as resources and then manually resolving the references using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` is not possible either, since `AppDomain` is not available in these types of project.

Comment: Excluding ILMerge, there's not a good way to do what you want. Can I ask why you want to do this? Is it because you just want a single binary that teams reference? If so, have you considered producing a NuGet package or Extension SDK so that developers can reference all the binaries in a single gesture?

Comment: @DavidKean You predicted quite well, what I actually want is to make available for other developers in my company an assembly which depends on many other assemblies and I want to make it so they have minimal work to do when adding the required references. NuGet didn't cross my mind, isn't it intended for public projects only?

Comment: NuGet isn't just for public consumption at all. NuGet supports internal published feeds, or even pointing to network shares. We (Microsoft) have a entire divisions that publish their "SDKs" as Nupkgs and have individual teams consume that. The other alternative is Extension SDKs which are a similar concept. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161096.aspx for a comparison between them.

Comment: @DavidKean This is great, I've always liked how practical NuGet is for managing references. I'll compare the methods and see what works best for us. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidKean I eventually chose NuGet with internal package feeds, that's a very useful feature for this kind of scenario.